# Question of "may" and "might"

Tags: usage

[This discussion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51281/might-may-could-would-have-been-able-to) clarifies the difference between "may" and "might".

Now my question **to the more knowledgeable native English speakers**:

***Is any of them preferred over the other in every-day speech?*** Maybe a more practical rule about when to use one and when the other? Thank you.

Background: I just realized recently that I forgot the existence of the word "might". Trying to bring it back to my vocabulary, I do not want to fall into the other extreme (using it too much).

Comment: You have to provide context. What type of sentence are you thinking of?

Answer (score 2):

When talking about *people*, or other things with agency (animals, companies, etc), we tend to use *may* for **permission** and *might* for **possibility**. However, that's only a tendency, not an absolute rule - and when talking about things that do not have agency, both just mean possibility.

> **May I** have the pleasure of this dance?
>   I **might** skip school tomorrow.
>
> It **may** rain tomorrow.
>   The menu **might** have changed.

I would say that *might* usually indicates a more remote possibility than *may*, but I'm not sure that everyone has a consistent understanding of that.

Just to confuse things, ***can*** and ***could*** are also used both for permission and possibility.

Comment: I've read that you prefer *may* in formal or academic language when you talk about possibility. You don't normally use *may* to ask questions about the possibility of something, but you can use *might* in such questions to make them formal. Is it true? (Thank you)