# Word-usage - May, might and Could (For if clauses and Non-if clauses)

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, modal-verbs, conditionals

I've been searching about this for a long time, but the answer is not clear. Is there a difference between May, might and could?  And, even further - Is there a difference when they are in a conditional sentence?

When I saw some posts on the internet, I just saw that the three are for possibilities. But, at school (and in some posts, too), I saw that may is different from might (might expresses a low possibility and may expresses a higher one). But , posts in which includes *Could*  , there's no degree saying which shows a high possibility or a low one.

See these examples:

> If I go to Brazil, I **may** eat Brazilians' food.
>
> If I go to Brazil, I **might** eat Brazilians'food.
>
> If I go to Brazil , I **could** eat Brazilians'food.

Is there any difference? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Might / May / Could / Would have been able to](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51281/might-may-could-would-have-been-able-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you some probability percentages for how I would use words expressing different degrees of possibility. These are *not* rules. They vary significantly by person, by situation, and *especially* by tone of voice. I am thinking here of these replacing the bolded words in your example sentence.

- **will**: 100%
- **probably will**: 90% - 100%
- **might**: 20% - 80%
- **may**: 10% - 50% (less likely than *might* for me since I don't use *may* very often, so I would stress it)
- **could** / **can**: greater than 0% (this deals more with *ability* than likelihood)